# String resource from .resw for Data Binding in Windows 8

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime

String resource from `.resw` for Data Binding in Windows 8.

In Windows Phone I use follow:

1. Create `AppStrings.resx` and put all strings on it.
2. Create class `StringResources`, with field which returned instance of `AppStrings.resx`.
3. Add `StringResources` to `ApplicationResource`.

StringResources.cs

```
 public class StringResources
    {
        private static AppStrings _resources;

        public static AppStrings LocalizedResources
        {
            get { return _resources ?? (_resources = new AppStrings()); }
        }
    }
```

In App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <res:StringResources x:Key="Strings"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Use my resource from xaml like.

```
 Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.StringName, Source={StaticResource Strings}}"
```

All works great, but I can't do it in Windows 8.
I am in searching similar way of usage `DataBinding` with string resources on Windows 8.

**NOTE:** 
I checked [MSDN Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-cd0c6eaa), but can't find what I need.
I also check [ResW File Code Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ab88efd-1afb-4ff5-9faf-8825a282596a), this is workable way, but so far-fetched.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same approach as on WP. Visual Studio extension PublicResXFileCodeGenerator is used to generate a strongly typed class with static properties corresponding to all your keys in resx file in WinPhone apps. But for some reason there is no such tool for W8 by default.

ResW File Code Generator Visual Studio extesion is doing the same thing.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ab88efd-1afb-4ff5-9faf-8825a282596a

Install it and then you just need to set 'Custom Tool' field to ReswFileCodeGenerator (in properties of your default AppStrings.resw file) and set Custom Tool Namespace to give a name space to your AppStrings class.
It will auto generate AppStrings class and then you can use it like in WP.

**NOTE**: This extension regenerates AppStrings calss every time you change you AppString.resw file and VS 2013 will mark the constructor 'new ResourceLoader("AppStrings")' as deprecated. You need to use CoreWindow independent method ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse("AppString") instead (GetForCurrentView("AppString") would not work).